# dc.jc: Incorrect subgroup filtering

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

In example on http://jsfiddle.net/dtyeL7g7/9/, 
GUI filtering works on "normal" bar chars like 1st two (actions, all delays)

On the other hand, when doing the same on one subgroup of delays (last two graphs C1,C2), GUI removes all results from all graphs.

Subgrouping is realized by:

```
function filterActionType(source_group, actionType) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
            console.log( "filter d: ", d );
               var d2 = d.key.split(";")
               var delay = d2[0];
               var a1 = d2[1];
               var r = a1 === actionType;
               console.log( "filter result r: "+ r );
              return r;
            });
        }
    };
}


var c1Dim = ndx.dimension(function(d){
    return d.delay +";"+ d.action;
    });

var c1Group = filterActionType(c1Dim.group(), 'C1' );
```

and key is accessed by:

```
    .keyAccessor( function(v) {
      console.log( "keyAccessor v: ", v);
      var v2 = v.key.split(";")[0]; 
      console.log( "keyAccessor result v2: ", v2);
      return v2;
    })
```